# Using the GDI+ API to draw an image

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the `GDI+` API just to display an image (*bmp*) on the screen. Here is the code of the function doing the task:

```
void drawImg_ArmorInfo_PupupWnd(HDC hdc) {

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Image* image = new Image(L"C:/Users/Darek/F2 stuff/art/intrface/armor_info_1.bmp");
    int a1 = image->GetWidth();
    int a2 = image->GetHeight();

    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);

    delete image;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting an exception: `Access violation writing location 0xXXXXXXXX` after calling the `GdiplusShutdown` function. What's interesting when I comment out the

```
Graphics graphics(hdc);
graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

part the program runs without any problems but, of course, the image isn't drawn. When I comment out the call to `GdiplusShutdown` function - no problems again.

What's wrong with the code and what can be the reason of the problem here?

Comment: GdiplusStartup/Shutdown belongs in main().

Comment: [Drawing a Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-drawing-a-line-use) -- See the scope of the two paired calls.

Comment: @Hans Passant "GdiplusStartup/Shutdown belongs in main" - can You be so nice and explain what You mean? How can it belongs to the `main` since I'm calling it fro the `drawImg_ArmorInfo_PupupWnd` function!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graphics` falls out of the scope after the `GdiplusShutdown` so it cannot destruct correctly.

Try this:

```
Graphics * graphics = new Graphics(hdc);
graphics->DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
delete graphics;
```

Comment: There is literally no place in C++ for `delete`, and next to no reason to use `new`. C++' power feature are custom destructors. Declare a struct whose sole purpose is to initialize GDI+ in its constructor, and shut down GDI+ in its destructor.

Comment: @Oleg Korzhukov. Yours solution DO work BUT can You be so kind and explain me HOW does is the `graphics` object is related to the `GdiplusShutdown` function since in a call to `GdiplusShutdown` there is no reference to the `graphics` object !?

Comment: derec_911, yes there are no direct reference in **your** code, but look that MS wrote.

MSDN: _The `GdiplusStartup` function initializes Windows GDI+. Call `GdiplusStartup` before making any other GDI+ calls, and *call GdiplusShutdown when you have finished using GDI+*._

You have not finished using GDI+ until the `graphics` destructed.

Comment: @IInspectable is right, but I guess, we are not to teach the RAII here. Original code is rather short, and it is impractical to create new objects for religious reasons.

Comment: @OlegKorzhukov Thx for answer but can You please explain me WHY when i use the "normal" object instead of the pointer (`Graphics graphics(hdc)` vs `new Gdiplus::Graphics(hdc)`) the problem occurs?

Comment: @darek_911 If you do not use the pointer: *after* `GdiplusShutdown()`, but *before* the function execution ended, object `graphics` is still exists. At the end of the function execution all objects created in its stack ("not pointers") are destroyed. So  destructor `graphics.~Graphics()` is called (not by you, but "by C++"). This function requires valid GDI+ environment, but you already shut it down. Using the pointer allows you do destroy the `graphics` object before the shutdown of GDI+.

Comment: By default, objects in C++ have automatic storage duration. When an object goes out of scope its destructor runs. A pointer's destructor is trivial (it does nothing).

Comment: @OlegKorzhukov. Ok friend, but even if I comment out the `delete graphics` line the solution with pointer DOES work! (no exception). How can You explain this?

Comment: *"A pointer's destructor is trivial (it does nothing)."*

Comment: @darek_911 When you create `graphics` using `new`, it is created in **heap**, which is "global" not in **stack**, which is local to function. If you do not call `delete graphics`: it is not deleted, it still exists in the heap, its destructor never called (the one which requires valid GDI+ environment and causes access violation if cannot access it), and after the function ended, you have no means to delete the `graphics` anymore, you have created a memory leak.

Comment: @OlegKorzhukov Thx Oleg for detailed and valuable answer BUT that's the basics I've already know:-) As I've written EVEN if I do not call delete on the graphics obj the code DO works?!